# How to use multiple instance of an user control in a xaml

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM. I have got a question in my recent interview.

There is a user control with a title and a status control (will display in different color to indicate status Green/Red/Yellow). I need to display 3 different instance of this user control in a window with different titles and status.

Apologies, I have no code snippet for this as it was my interview question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing is often easier to accomplish with a DataTemplate rather than a user control.

Let's say you have a class called "StatusItem" that looks like this:-

```
public class StatusItem
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public StateColour State {get;set;}
}
```

Where StateColour is an enum:

```
public enum StateColour
{
   Red,
   Green,
   Blue
}
```

Now let's say you want to expose three different status objects from your VM, e.g.:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public StatusItem Status1 {get;set;}        
    public StatusItem Status2 {get;set;}        
    public StatusItem Status3 {get;set;}

    ...
}
```

In a real app you should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on these classes. Without this, the UI will not "refresh" if (say) the Title or State property value was updated.

Next, in your XAML you would define a DataTemplate for the StatusItem class, in the "resources" section of your page/window:-

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ns:StatusItem}">
   <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
      <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30">
         <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="{x:Static ns:StateColour.Red}">
                     <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                  </DataTrigger>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="{x:Static ns:StateColour.Green}">
                     <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                  </DataTrigger>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="{x:Static ns:StateColour.Blue}">
                     <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                  </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </Rectangle.Style>
      </Rectangle>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then in the "body" of your XAML use a ContentControl where you want the three status controls to appear, e.g.

```
<StackPanel>
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding Status1}" />
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding Status2}" />
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding Status3}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Each ContentControl will be automatically rendered using the earlier DataTemplate, thanks to the DataTemplate's "DataType=".

Note this code is straight out of my head and therefore untested. You will need to substitute "ns" for the correct namespace of the class and enum involved. There's a lot more to MVVM than I can cover here, but hopefully this should give you a hint as to how to achieve what you want.